# Unable to find the absolute path of /tmp directory on Heroku Server

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I am developing an App on Facebook,which require users to upload their images on my server and i could post it on their page.I am unable to post that picture to Facebook,however if only message is present its getting posted very fine.I feel the problem is with /tmp directory of heroku since it process uploaded files in a different manner then normal php thing.I don't know if the absolute path is the server(MYAPP.herokuapp.com/tmp) or apps.facebook.com/tmp.Do i need to explicitly create a tmp folder there,if so.how??
Here is a snippet of my "POST" code:

```
   $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
   $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]));
   if ((($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
   || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
   || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png")
   || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
   && ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 20000)
   && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
   {
         if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] > 0)
          { 
            echo "invalid picture ..please try again";
          }
         else
          {
            echo "successful";
          }
   }
   else
   {
     echo "invalid picture ..please try again";
   }
   $ext=explode("image/", $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"]);
   foreach($ext as $e)
   {
     $v .=$e ;
   }
   $path ='https://apps.facebook.com/pagecron'.$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'].'.'                 
   .$v;
   $parameters = array('message' => $_POST['message'],
                      'picture' => $path,
                      'link' => $_POST['link'],
                      'name' => $_POST['name'],
                      'caption' => $_POST['caption'],
                      'description' => $_POST['description']
                     );
```

Comment: Isn't the absolute path `/tmp` ?

Comment: @Igy sir,i mean since posting a picture on facebook requires the full path (link) of the picture,I am not able to find that path from heroku,i really searched hard on internet and read docs about heroku,they says to use amazon s3 storage for storage purpose,i don't have a credit card so i can't.And i don't even want to store the users picture,just want it to get posted on facebook.Any help???

Comment: The `/tmp` directly almost certainly isn't accessible publicly via HTTP(S) - if you're uploading the images to the Facebook API upload the file directly, not via URL

Comment: @Igy file directly mean???i read facebook developers blog there is one way to upload a photo using graph url which we can be directly put in the action field  and it is working very fine.But with that the problem is users will be limited to post only pictures which i don't want another thing is we wont able to redirect our user in that case

Comment: @Igy And its my pleasure the facebook API developer himself is answering me.Please consider am just a kid.

Comment: Suppose your app's canvas url is `https://x-y-z.herokuapp.com` and you have a `images` folder present at root; then you can access any image through `https://x-y-z.herokuapp.com/images/IMAGE_NAME`

Comment: @Sahil thats the problem,since heroku doesnt support storage of files from users,i cant store my visitor's images which they upload on my server to get posted on facebook.one alternative i foudn to post on facebook is by directly posting the image to facebook using url and setting that url as action field on uploading form,this way i am able to post the picture to facebook.But since my app supports posting picture on multiple pages at a time,i am confused how to process that action field url to post on multiple pages

Comment: @Sahil if you can tell me any alternative to heroku app engine to run my php based app (it must support user file uploads) then also it will be good for me

Comment: You can initiate chat here itself

Comment: @Sahil ok have created on room,problem discussion with sahil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a picture from Computer and post it on Facebook multiple pages at a time using PHP](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14172818/get-a-picture-from-computer-and-post-it-on-facebook-multiple-pages-at-a-time-usi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use this :

```
if(session_id()){}
else{session_start();}
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$x=realpath($_FILES['source']['tmp_name']);
$parameters = array('message' => $_POST['message'],'source' =>'@' . $x );
$parameters['access_token'] = $_SESSION['active']['access_token'];
$check=$facebook->api('/me/photos','POST',$parameters);
```